# Windows doesn't update last access time if opening it with fopen()

Tags: python, c#, windows, fopen

As the title says i am trying to determine if someone has accessed a file even using fopen.I have enabled Windows NTFS Last Access Time Stamps but it only works if i open the file normal.Is there any way to extend this functionality while using fopen?

Comment: tell the reason to use `os.fopen`?

Comment: @LeiYang for example encrypt the file.